# Powershell - Find all extensions on network shares

Tags: powershell, file-extension, shared-directory

I'm new to PS scripting (really, I started today) and, for a project, I need to create a .txt file with all the extensions from all shared folders on the local machine (a Windows file server).

I think I'm on the right path with this :

```
get-childitem -Path C:\test -Recurse | select extension -unique > $PSScriptRoot\ExtensionList.txt
```

It's doing exactly what I want for a given path and all subfolders but now I need to apply this to all shared folders on the machine.

I was able to list all the shared folder's path with this command :

```
$Shares=   @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Share | 
                    Select Name,Path,Type | 
                    Where-Object { $_.Type -match '0|2147483648' } | 
                    Select -ExpandProperty Path | 
                    Select -Unique)
Write-Host $Shares
```

Now I'm stuck, I suppose I need to use the foreach command but I can't find the way to make it work.

Can someone help me put this together ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something similar to this:

```
$Shares = @( Get-CimInstance Win32_Share | Where-Object { $_.Type -match '0|2147483648' } | Select -Unique )
ForEach ( $Share In $Shares ) { Get-ChildItem -Path $Share.Path -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore | Select -Unique -ExpandProperty Extension }
```

*I'll leave you to split the lines to match your particular style and to output to a file, (I'd advise that you consider using `Out-File` instead of `>` for that)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Get-SMBShare` cmdLet:

```
Get-SMBShare | Foreach {
  Get-ChildItem "\\$($_.name)" | Select-Object Extension -Unique
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help! I was able to figure it out.

The following script will gather all extensions on shared folders, sort them, eliminate duplicates and empty lines, add "*' before the extension and create a file list.txt with the result.

```
#get shares
$Shares = @( Get-CimInstance Win32_Share | 
Where-Object { $_.Type -match '0|2147483648' } | 
Select -Unique )

#list all extensions
ForEach ( $Share In $Shares ) { Get-ChildItem -Path $Share.Path -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore | Select -Unique -ExpandProperty Extension | out-file C:\extensions\List1.txt -append }

#remove empty lines
@(gc C:\extensions\List1.txt) -match '\S'  | out-file C:\extensions\List2.txt

#Add * before extention type
gc C:\extensions\List2.txt | %{"*$_"} | out-file C:\extensions\List3.txt

#Sort by name
gc C:\extensions\List3.txt | sort | get-unique > C:\extensions\List4.txt

#Remove duplicates
$hash = @{}      
gc C:\extensions\List4.txt | 
%{if($hash.$_ -eq $null) { $_ }; $hash.$_ = 1} > C:\extensions\List.txt

#Delete list1-4
Remove-Item C:\extensions\List1.txt, C:\extensions\List2.txt, C:\extensions\List3.txt, C:\extensions\List4.txt
```